# php mysql query finding closest results

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, search

How would the best way to approach this problem be?

- Search for user by first name, where the parameter is a string. The result should display a list
  of the 10 users whose first name is closest to the searched string.

Clearly there are different ways to approach this one. Is there any mysql functionality that does this already?

Should I just query all my rows and run some kind of search function?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM engine for the table?  How many users do you plan on having in the DB?

Comment: You could use the [SOUNDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function of MySQL if you mean "sounds close enough".

Comment: 10, 000 it is just a test query I have to write. No worry about efficiency on this one.

Comment: I just found http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_levenshtein.asp which is looking like the way to go in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MySQL Full-Text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) which will automatically return results based on relevancy, though it will not work with InnoDB.

Comment: There is a pretty big drawback to using MySQL Full-Text searches: you cannot search for substrings (just for prefixes).